# Nested properties with common affix

Tags: css, colors, sass, nested-properties

In SCSS, properties with common **prefix** can be described as nested properties. Thus, as in the [example](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#nested_properties),

```
.funky{
  font: 2px/3px{
    family: fantasy;
    size: 30em;
    weight: bold;
  }
}
```

is compiled to:

```
.funky{
  font: 2px/3px;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 30em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

How do I do a similar thing with properties with common **affix**? How can I write a nested property that would be compiled to this:

```
.funky{
  color: red;
  background-color: green;
  border-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sass has no construct for such a concept.  You'll have to patch it or write a verbose mixin to do it.

```
@mixin color($background: null, $border: null, $font: null) {
    background-color: $background;
    border-color: $border;
    color: $font;
}

.foo {
    @include color($background: green, $font: red);
}
```

Comment: The `$` in `@include color($background: green, $font: red);` does not look nice. Is it possible to pass something like a hash or keyword arguments?

Comment: OK, I realized that SASS keyword arguments need `$`. Thanks for the help.